# Почему нужно устанавливать программы, а не просто скачивать готовые файлы с кодом? Что устанавливается при установке?

Tags: c#, установка

Я новичок в создании ПО, отсюда и этот глупый, но важный для моего понимания вопрос.

Моя теория такова: устанавливается всё, что необходимо программе для работы (для программы на C# устанавливается .NET нужной версии, CLR и т.п.).

Верна ли моя теория? Если нет, объясните мне, пожалуйста, что же всё таки заставляет программу устанавливаться?

Comment: на linux большинство программ имеют исходники. А на linux centos (и некоторых других) устанавливать  через исходники -- вообще true (т.е. обычное дело). Там если программе нужно что-то еще, нужно просто аналогично установить это что-то

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Проверяется, что программа вообще заработает на этой конфигурации (есть нужное железо и ПО)
2. Копируется нужное системное барахло, это вы верно указали.
3. Файлы программы рассовываются куда надо. Это может быть важно, если программа должна взаимодействовать с другими программами.
4. Записывается конфигурация системы и программы - прописывается, какие файлы надо открывать установленной программой, где будут ярлыки, должна ли она автоматически запускаться при старте ОС.

Все это, конечно, можно сделать и руками, но проще и надежнее автоматизировать процесс.